# There is a way to print the content of a txt file and save it again as a new file in C?

Tags: c, file

I'm stuck on how to write a code in C to print the content of a txt file and save it back as a new file (with another name). Does anyone know how to do this?

The txt has the following structure:

- Sentence1.
- Sentence2.
- Sentence3.
- Sentence4.
- Sentence5.
- Sentence6.
- Sentence7.

(Obviously the sentence have words.)

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Please expand your post so that it meets the site's guidelines, as laid out in the [tour], the [ask] page, the [mre] page, and the [help/on-topic].

Comment: One route: `fopen, fgets, fputs, fclose`.

Comment: `int c; FILE *ofp = fopen("output_file", "w"); FILE *ifp = fopen("input_file", "r"); while( (c = getc(ifp)) != EOF ){ putc(ofp, c); }`